# PHP Set a hook in a checkbox if the value is 1 or uncheck if the value is 0

Tags: php, checkbox

i hope you can help me, i think the solution is simple, but i am beginner, so kick my brain.

Now i want on a new page that the checkbox will be shown as either checked or unchecked depending on the result.

The results are available as 1 or 0, but how can I now display a checkbox as checked or unchecked?

I'm grateful for every tip.

Comment: `$checked = $result==1 ? 'checked' : '';`

Answer (score 0):

If it is Javascript you can add your PHP variable to it like so:

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="'.$checkboxValue'.">
```

If you wanted to get the value of the check box you have to submit it in a form like so:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

index.php

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['checkbox1']){
        $checkboxValue = $_POST['checkbox1'];
    }
?>
```

**Note:** The $_POST value is from the name attribute of your checkbox